# How can a template class use the types in another template class in C++?

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have a template class that depends on another template class. How can TemplateClassB use the type TypeA of TemplateClassA?

```
template <int L>
class TemplateClassA {
public:
  typedef unsigned TypeA;
};

template <typename E, typename F>
class TemplateClassB {
  TemplateClassA::TypeA var;   //error: invalid use of template-name 'TemplateClassA' without an argument list
}; 

int main(){
  TemplateClassA<1> A = TemplateClassA<1>();
}
```

Comment: You need to specify a template parameter for `TemplateClassA` in the declaration of `var`, and also use `typename`

Comment: Please call them "class templates". They are templates that make classes, not a funny kind of class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Brian says, use

```
typename TemplateClassA<L>::TypeA var;
```

where `L` is some `int`.

Comment: if L is not known beforehand, then TemplateClassB has to have another template parameter, L, is that correct?

Comment: yes, you'd have template <typename E, typename F, int L>
class TemplateClassB {